# Can not connect with Casbah but it works with ReactiveMongo

Tags: mongodb, scala, casbah, reactivemongo

I have an issue connecting to my mongo database with Casbah and it works fine with ReactiveMongo. Here is the code used with Casbah:
`val client = MongoClient(MongoClientURI("my_uri"))` and with ReactiveMongo: `this.driver(actorSystem).connection(MongoConnection.parseURI("my_uri"))`. the error I get with with Casbah is: `{ "serverUsed" : "host:27017" , "ok" : 0.0 , "errmsg" : "auth failed" , "code" : 18}`. Any idea where this could come from ?

Comment: You're getting an "auth failed" message - how are you setting your mongodb credentials?

Comment: In both ways they're set in the mongo uri like this: `mongodb://login:password@host:port/database`

Comment: What version of MongoDB and what version of Casbah?

Comment: Mongodb version 2.6.8 and Casbah version 2.8.1

Comment: What does `db.getUser(<login>)` output? http://docs.mongodb.org/manual/reference/method/db.getUser/

Comment: Thanks Ross, I've found the issue the user does not exist in the database. If I try to login without login/password it works. But I don't understand why ReactiveMongo can login but Casbah can't.

Answer (score 0):

You may need to explicitly set the `authMechanism` property if not using the default for the MongoDB Server.

Before MongoDB 3.0 the default authentication mechanism was `MONGODB-CR`, the "MongoDB Challenge-Response" protocol.  In MongoDB 3.0 the default was changed to `SCRAM-SHA-1`.

If no `authMechanism` is set then the underlying Java driver will pick the most secure mechanism available based on the sever version.

Try updating your Connection String to:

```
mongodb://login:password@host:port/database?authMechanism=MONGODB-CR
```